# How to make a full width submenu in foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make the submenu's width 100% but its not working.

If anyone could help me it would be highly appreciated

http://codepen.io/maiterosalie/pen/OMgeeZ

```
<div class="row" id="menu">
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <a href="#" id="logo">
        <img src="http://indexrd.com/application/public/img/logo.svg" width="60" height="60" id="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="small-8 .small-offset-1 columns">
      <li><a class="trans active" href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="trans" id="servicios" href="#">Sub Menu</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a class="trans" href="#">link #1</a></li>
          <li><a class="trans" href="#">link #2</a></li>
          <li><a class="trans" href="#">link #3</a></li>
          <li><a class="trans" href="#">link #4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="trans" href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a class="trans" href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please define "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div element `< div class="row" id="menu">` is not closed with a `< / div>`. You need that so your coding is correct.
You can also add `style="width: 100%;"` to the top `div` class, or however you want your menu to look.
This is because the `div` element is a container and you have to have a specific width set to it. So whatever you put inside can expand to the amount of percent you chose to make it.
Hope that helped.